# c# threading weird ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, console, threadabortexception

I am running into a very strange issue.  I am sure its something small but I am pulling my hair out on this one...

I am working on integrating a third party lib into my application.  I downloaded the lib and it came with sample code.  I was able to build and run the sample code with no problem.  I copy the lib + the sample code into my own solution folder without changing anything in both projects, added them into my own solution, built and run.  I get ThreadAbortException at the end of my sample app.  This used to work in separate folder?!!?!

The code opens a socket connection within a listening thread.  The thread monitors and consumes the socket information.  Then before the program exits, it does a runner.Abort() where runner is the thread.  What I can't figure out, is why is it not throwing ThreadAbortException in its original unzipped folder.  But when I copied exactly into my own solution it will throw?

I did not see any use of Thread.ResetAbort().

Need some help on this one.  Thanks in advance.

What I have tried:
Changing .net framework version(no matter how I change, original directory will run fine but my own solution will choke on ThreadAbortException)

This is on Visual Studio 2013 community edition.

Thank you for reading.

edited below***

Config files are identical.  The bin directory shows the generated pdb files have size differences but other files seem to be identical in size.  The code that did not work have smaller pdb files.

I deleted the original directory's bin for both the lib project and the sample project, removed the reference from the sample project and re-add it from the solution. built, and it builds the same size(bigger than other solution). Ran it and it exited fine without ThreadAbortException. Then I did the same thing under my own solution and it builts with smaller size pdb and the ThreadAbortException showed up

I also verified that both instances of Visual studio are 2013 community.

Comment: can you please put your code here?

Comment: app.config file maybe? Have you compared the *executables* generated in both places? (If you copy the exe from the original folder to your own directory, what happens?)

Comment: @JonSkeet always something new to know from you :)

Comment: Search for Thread.Join() in the sample code. Or maybe there is some kind of global exception handling routine.

Comment: @JonSkeet sample.exe.config is identical.  it only contains .net framework version in there.  The pdb file for the sample app under my solution is smaller than the one in the original location.  This is true for both the third party api project as well as the sample project.

Comment: @Alex I did not find any Join

Comment: The PDB file size change could be due to the debug information including paths. But delete the pdb files - just look at the executables.

Comment: @JonSkeet I deleted the original directory's bin for both the lib project and the sample project, removed the reference from the sample project and re-add it from the solution. built, and it builds the same size(bigger than other solution). Ran it and it exited fine without ThreadAbortException. Then I did the same thing under my own solution and it builts with smaller size pdb and the ThreadAbortException showed up.

Comment: 2 questions. Why is there a runner.Abort()? Why not just set a flag for the thread to exit? And do you get the error when you run the exe's normally without debugging? CLR Exceptions might be enabled in your sample app, but was not in the other one.

Comment: Again, ignore the PDB size. Just to check, are you copying the whole *solution* from one place to another, or including some *projects* into a different solution? Are you running the same *application* in both cases?

Comment: @Jaques I do ask about that myself.  Why their framework uses Abort() instead of setting flags.  These projects I didn't write.

Comment: @JonSkeet There are only 2 projects in their entire solution.  I have a solution that contains 50 projects or so.  I copied both projects into a location more suitable for my solution.  Then added both copied projects into my solution.  Build and run.  I think I will try and build the lib under the solution that actually runs, then copy over the executable and reference that instead.  It sucks to do this but at least I can see if I can see if I can spin up and tear down without issues.  I didn't intend on changing their code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a brand new solution, put the third party projects in there.  Then add my old projects in the new solution one by one.  It is still unclear to me why it happened.  But I am going to move on for now.